# nondimensionalization and change of coordinates of gradient

Tags: vector-analysis, change-of-variable

Given the variables $(\theta,r,x)$ and the nondimensionalization (change of coordinates):

$$
\bar{\theta}=\frac{\theta}{\theta_0}\\
\bar{r}=\frac{r}{r_o}\\
\bar{x}=\frac{x}{h}
$$

The gradient of a scalar field $\phi$ in this coordinate system is written as:
$$
\nabla\phi=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\theta}\hat{\theta}+\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial r}\hat{r}+\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\hat{x}
$$

How do I write the gradient in the new coordinate system?
I am tempted to write it as
$$
\nabla\phi = 
\frac{1}{r_o\bar{r}}\frac{1}{\theta_0}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\bar{\theta}}\hat{\bar{\theta}}+
\frac{1}{r_o}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial \bar{r}}\hat{^\bar{r}}+
\frac{1}{h}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial \bar{x}}\hat{\bar{x}}
$$

Not sure if this is exactly true and, if it is, what is a good way to actually prove it.

Comment: This is correct imo, since you are only doing linear scaling.

Comment: It looks OK, except you still have a $\theta$. You forgot to add the bar on top of it

Comment: corrected it. So it seems to be ok. Thank you guys. Does the same kind of logic applies to the Divergent operator? I.e., just change the differential operators to the new ones and do the change of coordinates?